# laravel eloquent pivot table query "ambiguous column name"

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a pivot table between two the tables users and products. However when I run `$user->Cart()->Get();` I get the below error:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 631: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1 ambiguous column name: main.cart.products_id (SQL: select
>   "cart".*, "cart"."user_id" as "pivot_user_id", "cart"."products_id" as
>   "pivot_products_id" from "cart" inner join "cart" on "cart"."id" =
>   "cart"."products_id" where "cart"."user_id" = 2)

This is the user model:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    ...

    public function Cart()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cart', 'cart', 'user_id', 'products_id');
    }
}
```

The products model:

```
class Products extends Model
{
    ...
    public function Cart()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cart', 'cart', 'products_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

The cart model:

```
class Cart extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'cart';

    public function Products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Products', 'products', 'user_id', 'products_id');
    }


    public function User()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Products', 'users', 'user_id', 'products_id');
    }
}
```

The cart schema:

```
        Schema::create('cart', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->integer('products_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('products_id')->references('id')->on('products')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your User model, the cart() method should have App\Product as the first parameter:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    public function carts()
    {
        // User can have many "products" in cart
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'cart', 'user_id', 'products_id'); 
    }
}
```

Same thing for Product:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function carts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'cart', 'products_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Then your cart model:

```
class Cart extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cart';

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'id', 'product_id');
    }


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

PS: Note that it's best practise to keep the model class name as Singular (Product not Products) and method name should start with lowercase letter (carts not Carts)